# Why doesn't the information render in the modal?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to have a modal display information from an API. The program outputs which drink is selected in console, but the information does not render - I get a blank modal. I get no error messages.

```
    const DrinkPopup = (props) => {

  let [drinkDetails,setDrinkDetails] = useState([])
  let selectedDrinkId = props.drink

  const getDrinkAsync = async (selectedDrinkId) => {
    try {
      let response = await fetch('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i='+selectedDrinkId);
      let data = await response.json();
      setDrinkDetails(data.drinks)
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  
  useEffect (() =>  { 
    getDrinkAsync(selectedDrinkId)
    console.log(selectedDrinkId)  
  },[]);
  


  return(
    <Modal isVisible={props.modalVisible}
    onBackdropPress={()=>{props.setModalVisible(false)}} //allows closing modal by tapping outside it or back button
    onBackButtonPress={()=>{props.setModalVisible(false)}} 
    animationIn={"slideInUp"}>  
      <View style={styles.infocard}>
          <View style={styles.titleBox}>
            <Text style={styles.header}>{drinkDetails.idDrink}</Text>
          </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>


  )


}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  redCircle: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 50/2,
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  infocard: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: 15,
    margin: 20,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
    borderTopRightRadius: 20,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 20,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 20,
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 26,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
    padding: 5,
  },
  titleBox: {
    flexDirection: "row", 
    padding: 20, 
    justifyContent:"space-between",
  },
  picture: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  field: {
    flexDirection: "row", 
    justifyContent:"space-between",
    padding: 5,
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  info:{
    fontSize:16,
  },
  picturebox:{
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10
  }
});

export default DrinkPopup;
```

Any suggestions for how to troubleshoot this? As said above, I get no error messages and the useEffect is logging the correct ID to console. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Are you sure it's not working correctly and display an undefined value? Looks like drinkDetails is a list. Does drinkDetails.idDrink actually exist?? Try using a string literal to test.

Comment: @windowsill I just tested it, drinkDetails.idDrink is coming out as undefined, but drinkDetails on its own spits out what looks like what I want. drinkDetails *should* be an object so I can reference the elements of it, but it doesn't look like that's what is happening.

Comment: Isn't your answer an array ? Or why did you initialize your value with an array ? I see no `drinkDetails.map`

Comment: Can you please see if `<Text style={styles.header}>{"definitely exists"}</Text>` renders anything.

Comment: Your example with a string literal renders for me. Just update your text component to show something that is not undefined.